# What temperature does the average stainless steel kettle left on a stovetop reach?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, estimation, thermal-conductivity

I was trying to find out the time it'd take for a liter of water in a kettle to boil on a normal stovetop (avg temp:400°C) but I got stuck on heat energy of the kettle absorbed from the stovetop by the kettle

Comment: Youd have to know the mass and the material (as best you can the heat capacity) of the kettle.

Comment: The heat energy absorbed by the kettle has fairly little effect on the boiling time - water absorbs 10 times as much heat per degree change as steel does, not to mention the fact that you likely have a greater mass of water than kettle. For a 2:1 water:kettle mass, around 95% of the transferred energy goes into the water rather than the kettle - you probably have more error in estimating the efficiency of heat transfer from the stove to the kettle.  Accounting for the heat absorbed by the kettle itself isn't going to change your estimate much.

Comment: Does the kettle left on the stove top contain water or is it empty?